# CLion not showing Google Tests in tree view

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, clion, jetbrains-ide

I've created a C++ project in CLion with support for Google Tests (based on a starter project available [here](https://github.com/axelkennedal/Clion-GoogleTest-Starter)).

I can run tests as expected, with the exception that they don't show up in the hierarchical tree view of the test runner:
[image]

What I would expect to see is the test suite name (`InputOutputTestSuite`) as a node, with the tests (`CanReadAndWriteEmptyBoard`, `CanReadAndWriteKingBoard`) in it as children. My test suite looks like this:

[image]

And I'm using a Google Test run configuration to run all test suites and all tests:
[image]

Any ideas why the tree view is not working?

**UPDATE:** The tree view shows only failed tests, by the look of it:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please enable `Show Passed` option (in red):

[image]